# Exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException when try access a mapped json file

Tags: java, json, spring

In my spring application, I am using json-taglibs to dinamically generate json files based on Lists of entities I retrieve from database and add to request in my controller. I am facing this error with one of this files:

```
Grave: Servlet.service() for servlet [json_dispatcher] in context with path [/loja] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.spring.webapp.lojavirtual.common.persistence.model.Categoria.id; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.spring.webapp.lojavirtual.common.persistence.model.Categoria.id] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Integer field com.spring.webapp.lojavirtual.common.persistence.model.Categoria.id to java.lang.String
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:379)
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:346)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4746)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4465)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:537)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.nullSafeSet(ManyToOneType.java:174)
    at org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.bindParameterValues(QueryLoader.java:613)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1900)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1861)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at com.spring.webapp.lojavirtual.config.hibernate.Dao.findByField(Dao.java:67)
    at com.spring.webapp.lojavirtual.config.hibernate.Dao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$75e094d4.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:711)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
    at com.spring.webapp.lojavirtual.produto.persistence.ProdutoDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b13352aa.findByField(<generated>)
    at com.spring.webapp.lojavirtual.produto.service.ProdutoService.listagem_por_categoria(ProdutoService.java:105)
    at com.spring.webapp.lojavirtual.produto.service.ProdutoService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5e9076b4.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:711)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
    at com.spring.webapp.lojavirtual.produto.service.ProdutoService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c1e4b579_2.listagem_por_categoria(<generated>)
    at com.spring.webapp.lojavirtual.produto.controller.ProdutoControler.listagem_por_categoria_json(ProdutoControler.java:100)
    at com.spring.webapp.lojavirtual.produto.controller.ProdutoControler$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d626f2a4.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:640)
    at com.spring.webapp.lojavirtual.produto.controller.ProdutoControler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e007cea4_3.listagem_por_categoria_json(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

the file presenting this error is:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="json" uri="http://www.atg.com/taglibs/json" %>
<json:object>
    <json:array name="produto" var="item" items="${lista}">
        <json:object>
                <json:property name="id" value="${item.id}"/>
                <json:property name="nome" value="${item.nome}"/>
                <json:property name="categoria" value="${item.categoria}"/>
        </json:object>
    </json:array>
</json:object>
```

and the method from controller which map this file is:

```
@RequestMapping(value="listagem.json")
public ModelAndView listagem_json() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("lista", produto.listagem());
    mav.setViewName("listagem_produto");
    return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(value="listagem_por_categoria.json", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView listagem_por_categoria_json(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String id_categoria = request.getParameter("id");
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

    if(id_categoria == null)
        mav.addObject("lista", produto.listagem());
    else
        mav.addObject("lista", produto.listagem_por_categoria(id_categoria));

    mav.setViewName("listagem_produto");
    return mav;
}
```

Note: the error only is triggered when I call the second method. The methods listagem() and listagem_por_categoria() from my service class are implemented this way:

```
@Transactional
public List<Produto> listagem() {
    return produto.findAll();
}

@Transactional
public Produto listagem(int id) {
    return produto.findById(id);
}

@Transactional
public List<Produto> listagem_por_categoria(String id_categoria) {
    return produto.findByField("categoria", id_categoria);
}
```

and in my DAO class, the methods findAll(), findById() and findByField(), are implemented this way:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional
public E findById(int id) {
    E instance = (E) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(entity, id);
    return instance;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional
public List<E> findByField(String field, String value) {
    String expressao = entity.toString();
    String nome_classe = new String();

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(expressao);
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        nome_classe = st.nextToken();
    }
    String query = "from "+nome_classe+" where "+field+" = :data";

    Query q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(query);
    q.setParameter("data", value);
    List<E> instance = q.list();
    return instance;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional
public List<E> findAll() {
    return (List<E>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(entity).setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();
}
```

anyone can see what's wrong with all that implementations?

Comment: Looks like you have a problem in mapping `com.spring.webapp.lojavirtual.common.persistence.model.Categoria.id to java.lang.String`. What type is the id in Categoria? I guess it is an Integer?

Comment: yes, it is. See here: https://github.com/klebermo/lojavirtual/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/webapp/lojavirtual/common/persistence/model/Categoria.java

Comment: Hibernate try to set a string to this integer field and this is not working. Is the table in you db also a int?

Comment: yes. the table is created by hibernate based on this entity class.

Comment: Can it be that thies must be  `return produto.findByField("categoria.id", id_categoria);`

Comment: this don't work too. I also try add a new method in my DAO class public List<E> findByIntegerField(String field, int value), and still don't work (same type of error occurs).

Comment: What is the value of `nome_classe` ?

Comment: Like this DAO class is a generic class, this variable receiver the name of each child class derived from this  class.

Comment: @KleberMta have you tryed q.setParameter("data", Integer.value.of(value));?

Comment: yes, it was my final solution. see answer below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Then I solve this problem by implementing two variations for the method findByField, one which accepts a String value, and other an Integer. The final code for this methods are:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional
public List<E> findByStringField(String field, String value) {
    String expressao = entity.toString();
    String nome_classe = new String();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(expressao);
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        nome_classe = st.nextToken();
    }
    String query = "from "+nome_classe+" where "+field+" = :data";
    List<E> instance = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(query).setString("data", value).list();
    return instance;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional
public List<E> findByIntegerField(String field, Integer value) {
    String expressao = entity.toString();
    String nome_classe = new String();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(expressao);
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        nome_classe = st.nextToken();
    }
    String query = "from "+nome_classe+" where "+field+" = :data";
    List<E> instance = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(query).setInteger("data", value).list();
    return instance;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this lines

```
String query = "from "+nome_classe+" where "+field+" = :data";
q.setParameter("data", value);
```

You pass `value` as a String, when hibernate construct a query it it replace a parameter with String. I think for category.Id you are using int type. 
Logic is following:
It expects Id as int and instead it gets String, then you got an exception.

upd:
If you don't want change implementation dramatically use `setParameter(String name, Object val, Type type)` to set column value correctly.
To get type use `sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(Class.class).getPropertyType("filedName")`

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what's happening in the method, which works in other cases in the same project. Can't figure out how to solve this issue in this specific case.

Comment: what library should I import to use Type? I am getting several options here in Eclipse.

Comment: check this http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html method with signature above

Comment: Ok, now I find the method in the documentation, but I change my call to q.setParameter("data", value, Hibernate.Integer); like in the example, and the Eclipse don't recognize the Hibernate.INTEGER (I try this two ways).